# Apply conditional formatting to cells containing "#N/A" in a large set

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to create one conditional formatting rule for a large cell range that impacts individual cells in that range that contain #N/A — the result of the =NA() function.

This is *almost* covered here: [How do I add conditional formatting to cells containing #N/A in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/1260014/how-do-i-add-conditional-formatting-to-cells-containing-n-a-in-excel)

The problem with that one is it doesn't use a single conditional formatting rule for a whole range of cells. I have perhaps a hundred different adjacent cells that I want to apply this conditional formatting to. It would be a nightmare to create and maintain that many conditional formatting rules.

Each cell should be conditionally formatted based in *its own content* — not on content in another cell.

**Why not dump =NA()?** I need to use =NA() because of charts that point to these cells. These cells I want to conditionally format point to other cells where daily data entry is done. When there's no data entry yet, I need a blank spot in the chart, but any string (like "No Entry" or even "") results in a chart entry that points to zero. So I have to use =NA() for the "No Entry" case.

Comment: so in your link change step seven where you create the applies to range to apply to the entire range and the formula would not have any `$` locking the reference, but be the address of the upper left cell of the range.

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner. That worked! Want to post your comment as the answer?